# Use RefreshControl to refresh asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, asynchronous, uirefreshcontrol

I am using AFNetworking to do some data loading from an API in order to refresh a UITableView. I'd like for the refresh controller to reflect this as so.

1. User pulls down and refresh wheel appears
2. API call goes out (async call)
3. API call returns success or error
4. UITableViewController finishes refresh, reloads data, and refresh wheel disappears

So I add a refresh control in viewDidLoad of my custom UIViewController (my table view is a subview of this master view) like below:

```
//Set up refresh controller
    tableController = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];
    tableController.view = self.subscriptionsTable;
    UIRefreshControl* refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(loadSubscriptions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    tableController.refreshControl = refresh;
```

I then have my refresh method: (all the `[connections asyncCall:self]` does is send an async call to the API via the AFNetworking pod, calling a completed method of my view controller when done)

```
-(void)loadSubscriptions{
    updated = YES;
    [connections asyncCall:self];
}
```

The view controllers completed methods looks like this

```
-(void)asyncDone(id)responseObject{
    tableData = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"Yay, I'm done!");
}
```

Unfortunately, the refresh control completes, of course, the minute the async call is sent, not when it finishes, leaving me with no updated data. How can I get that thing to hang out for a bit until the async call is actually completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`beginRefreshing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIRefreshControl/beginRefreshing) and [`endRefreshing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIRefreshControl/endRefreshing) when your async call starts and ends.  You'll also need to store a reference to your `refresh` control to do that.

So, in `loadSubscriptions` and `asyncDone:`:

```
-(void)loadSubscriptions{
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    updated = YES;
    [connections asyncCall:self]; 
}

-(void)asyncDone(id)responseObject{
    tableData = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"Yay, I'm done!");

    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

***Note:** A lot of async methods will call their completion block on a background thread, so you may need to dispatch that `endRefreshing` call to the main thread:*

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
});
```

Comment: That would work fine for when I want to manually trigger the refresh, but what about when they pull down? That automatically kicks off the begin refresh, calls my loadSubscriptions method, then calls endRefreshing when it completes, correct?

Comment: I'd have to test it to be sure, but I don't think the manual pull triggers `beginRefreshing` on its own; I think you still have to call it manually.

Comment: The docs state: _The control does not initiate the refresh operation directly. Instead, it sends the UIControlEventValueChanged event when a refresh operation should occur. You must assign an action method to this event and use it to perform whatever actions are needed._ I know that's directly talking about whatever operation you need to do to refresh your table view's data, but I think that also implies that you still need to call `begin/endRefreshing`.

Comment: You are correct it seems. AFNetworking handles the completion call on the main thread pre-packaged, so I didn't have to worry about that. Thanks for the education.